# How can I check if a site has not been directly reached?

Tags: php, hyperlink, voting-system

I have a voting script. It works well.

But I have a little problem. I don't want people to reach the vote submission page (the page where the vote is submitted to the db) directly. I want them to reach it only through a specific link.

My voting links:

```
<form>
<INPUT id="voteup1" type="BUTTON" VALUE="Vote it up!" ONCLICK="window.location.href='rankup.php?rankid=<? echo $id1; ?>'"> 
<INPUT id="votedown1" type="BUTTON" VALUE="Vote it down!" ONCLICK="window.location.href='rank.php?rankid=<? echo $id1; ?>'"> 
</form>
```

`$id1` is for defining the page that has been voted by the user. (It is important when the vote is added to the database)

I don't want people to reach rankup.php and rank.php directly. How could I prevent this?

Comment: If I call rank.php in my browser with *id=1* either in the URL line (GET request) or in the request header (POST request), I will always trigger an upvote. That's how HTTP works, and that's what makes sense. You could try playing with the Referer HTTP header, but often enough people disable those. Just leave it the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PHP's referrer variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to check that the referring URL belongs to you. But you can't rely on this 100% because this information may not be sent, and as it's part of the HTTP header the user can modify it if they like.

Sessions, as suggested, may be a good way to go about doing this. I'd choose sessions over cookies because users can disable their cookies on your site - and cookies are editable by the users. Sessions can only be edited by someone with access to your server (shared hosting usually).

Also I disagree with the way that you're doing this. Currently you're relying on user's having JavaScript enabled in their browsers. Some users don't have it enabled, some user's browsers don't support it. Some users even disable page redirects like that.

Personally, rather than using two scripts, I'd use a single script something like:

```
<form action="rank.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Vote up!" />
<input type="submit" value="Vote down!" />
</form>
```

In rank.php you detect which of the two buttons was pressed then run a function accordingly. You could use a session variable to store the ID of the item they'll be voting on and then read that ID from the session (make sure to escape it though) to ensure the ID can't be changed by the user at the last minute.

Hopefully that should give you some ideas.

Comment: Uh, "choose sessions over cookies" - you *do* realize sessions are usually implemented *using* cookies? So, no cookies (in 99.9% of the cases) means no sessions.

Comment: And when cookies aren't available for use the session is placed in the URL providing you've got it configured correctly.

Comment: I have a feeling this is no longer enabled by default; and (from the times I've been using it, sometime in 2005) the `trans-sid` feature had, psecifically, problems to support POST-ed forms.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP is stateless. There *is* no "direct/indirect" reaching of a page - each request is disconnected from the previous ones.

PHP has a mechanism to overcome this limitation: [Sessions](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php), which in turn use cookies.

So, you can set a session variable, to use as a flag: "can-vote-now", on your page where you'll have the voting buttons, and disallow voting if this is not set.

Pseudocode on your page w/ buttons:

```
set_voting_variable_for($poll_identifier);
```

Pseudocode on rankup.php:

```
if (!is_voting_variable_set($poll_identifier)) {
  // redirect away
} else {
  // register the vote
}
```

Oh, and note that pages that *make things happen* (so-called "non-idempotent" actions - e.g. increase vote count) shouldn't be reachable via `GET` (as GET is reserved for *showing things without changing them* - "idempotent" actions): you may want to make a form which uses `POST` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to use a cookie.  Only allow cookie values that you have generated within a certain timeframe be used to vote.  Otherwise, it would be easy to generate cookie values.

You can do this easily with PHP sessions.

You should also know that causing an action to happen (changing a vote count) on a `GET` request is not advised.  `GET` variables should only be used when retrieving data with a certain parameter.  Use `POST` instead.  Otherwise, every time some search bot stumbles across your voting script, votes will change.